# Summation - how to start from same index and power

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have arrived at the following:

$\displaystyle\sum_2 n(n-1)a_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_1 na_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^{n+2} - m^2\displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n = 0$

My goal is to somehow get all sums in the same power of $x$ and each sum must start from the same index of n. This will give me the possibility to then write everything in terms of one sum in which case since it's 0, the whole coefficient of it would be 0 which is great to calculate $a_n$.

Unfortunatelly, I tried everything but nothing works.

The first and second sums can start from 0, since for $n=0,n=1$, it will be 0.

$\displaystyle\sum_0 n(n-1)a_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_0na_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^{n+2} - m^2\displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n = 0$

Problem is I still got $x^{n+2}$ in 3rd one. we can start 3rd one from $n=2$, so

$\displaystyle\sum_0 n(n-1)a_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_0na_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_2 a_{n-2} x^n - m^2\displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n = 0$, but now index is from 2 which is not good.

If we start every index from 2, we can work it out, but then in the answer, I end up having $x^1$ and $x^2$ which prevents me from finding $a_n$.

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to treat the cases $n = 0$ and $n = 1$ separately. For $n = 0$ you get $-m^2a_0 = 0$, which implies $a_0 = 0$ (unless $m = 0$, which would have to be considered separately). For $n = 1$ you get $a_1 - m^2a_1 = 0$, which implies $a_1 = 0$ (unless $m = \pm 1$). Now you can continue with $n \geq 2$.

Also note that your equation can be simplified to
$$\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} (n^2-m^2)a_nx^n + \sum\limits_{n = 2}^{\infty} a_{n-2}x^n = 0.$$

Comment: Amazing, but now I'm a slightly more confused about my other question - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752745/frobenius-the-reason-by-changed-infinite-series

Answer (score 1):

You can use step function:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty [(n^2-m^2)a_n+u(n-2)a_{n-2}]x^n=0$$
where $u(k)=1$ for $k\geq 0$ and zero otherwise.