# Frobenius - the reason by changed infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, summation

When we're given the following differential:

$x^2y'' + xy' +(x^2 - m^2)y = 0$

Around $x=0$, the differential has singularity, so Frobenius suggested that if we want to represent $y(x)$ by infinite series around $x_0 = 0$, instead of using $y = \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n$, we need to use $y = x^k \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n$

I wonder what's the reason behind this ? How did frobenius figure it out ? One observation that I made is I tried $y = \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n$, but arrive at: $$\displaystyle\sum_2 n(n-1)a_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_1 na_n x^n + \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^{n+2} - m^2\displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n = 0$$

from which I can't make all of them with the same index and power of $x$.

**Question 1:** Is this the simple reason why $y = \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n x^n$ doesn't work for us in this case ? I asked a different question here [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752730/summation-how-to-start-from-same-index-and-power) - maybe that's the reason.

**Question 2:** What made frobenius think that multiplying it by $x^k$ would yield the correct result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to expect a solution to an ODE to be expressible as a power series (around $0$). In fact, you can easily write something down that does have non-analaytic solutions, e.g.
$$x^3y' - 2y = 0$$
has the non-analytic function
$$y(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} & \text{if } x > 0, \\ 0 & \text{if } x \leq 0,  \end{cases}$$
as one of its solutions.

Now, if you follow through the approach [in your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4752730/summation-how-to-start-from-same-index-and-power/4752748#4752748), you notice that unless $m$ is an integer, the only solution you get with the power series approach is the trivial one. Hence you need to be a bit more creative if you want to find non-trivial solutions. While it is difficult to know what exactly Frobenius was thinking, maybe he had an example in mind where he knew that his approach was working and then generalized, it does not seem too farfetched to try a fractional power series as the next best option. After all, solving ODEs is a lot of trial and error sometimes.

EDIT: Corrected $m^2$ not an integer to $m$ not an integer.

Comment: In my pevious question, it seems like $a_0=0$, $a_1 = 0$ and every $a_n$ ends up being 0, which means our solution function appeared $y(x) = 0$ which now i agree is not creative. (even when m is integer, we still get every $a_n$ to be 0)  What I wonder is when people say that normal approach $y = \displaystyle\sum_0 a_n (x-x_0)^n $ doesn't work for singular point, they mean that it works, but it just so trivial it doesn't end up helpful. Agreed ?

Comment: @Chemistry Yes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: note that when you say: that "unless $^2$
 is an integer, the only solution you get with the power series approach is the trivial one". I think whatever $m$ is(as long as not 0), you always end up with $a_n = 0$ (every a)

Comment: @Chemistry Are you sure about that? For $m = 1$ the equation $a_1 - m^2a_1 = 0$ does not determine the $a_1$ and so if you set $a_1$ to a constant different from $0$, you should actually get a power series with non-zero $a_1$, $a_3$, $a_5$ and so on.

Comment: What I meant was it depends on what $m$ is given in the differential equation. If $m=+-1$, I agree, $a_1$ doesn't necessarily have to be 0, but if $m!=0$ and $m!=1$, we always will get $a_n = 0$ (every a).

Comment: @Chemistry If $m = 2$, you run into the same thing. In this case $a_0 = a_1 = 0$, but $a_2$ is left undetermined, so you get a non-trivial solution again.

Comment: nope, $a_2$ depends on $a_0$ , so if $a_0 = 0$, $a_2$ would be 0

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that Frobenius was motivated by the [Euler equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Euler_equation) $a x^2 y'' + b y' + c y = 0$ where solutions involve $x$ to powers that may not be natural numbers.